# Security Updates for Windows 10 1511

Tags: windows-10

Will Microsoft still release security updates for Windows 10 1511 - and if yes, how long?

We've some issues with anniversary update 1607 and won't update some of our win10 installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft security update stick to the current branch (CB) and if it's a pro+ version you can delay the upgrade in your setting, that way it become a CBB. (Current Branch for Business)

The way it's done after those period, usually 6 months each, you no longer can receive any security update. Thus when another build will replace 1607, 1607 will become CBB and the newer build will become a CB. (and 1511 will be no longer serviced for security update)

To stay out of that cycle you must choose **LTSB** that act like a Windows 7/8/8.1, it will always receive security update, but will never got new feature (as the build number will never change)

A visual chart to give an example;

[image]

Comment: General purpose computers shouldn't use LTSB. `LTSB is not intended for deployment on most or all the PCs in an organization; it should be used only for special-purpose devices. As a general guideline, a PC with Microsoft Office installed is a general-purpose device, typically used by an information worker, and therefore it is better suited for the CB or CBB servicing branch.` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/waas-overview

Comment: @MDMarra Thanks for the note, but LTSB cost high too, it's Enterprise license, my goal was to state the alternative, as if the OP can't upgrade he will have to upgrade is computer park to have better 'windows 10's ready' computer